# Bash code: while loop does not work

Tags: bash, logging, while-loop

I tried to write a little bash code to write a temperaturelog. The into the logging file 100 timepoints and measuring points are written, then the data is moved to a temporary file and it should begin to record again into the original file. The temporary file is removed every 100 seconds because I only need the last minutes of record and want to prevent garbage.

Besides that the code might look unnecessarily complicated (I am a beginner) - Where is the mistake?
I expected the counter (printed just to see what is going on) would count to 100 but it only prints out:

```
1
2
```

and it writes only two timepoints instead of 100 into the files.
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0
#Initial temporary file is created
echo '' > temperaturelogtemporary.txt;

#100 timepoints are written into temperaturelog.txt   
while true; do
    echo `date` '->' `acpi -t`>> temperaturelog.txt;
    sleep 1;
    #as soon as 100 timepoints are recorded...      
    if [[ $COUNTER > 100 ]];
        then
                    #...the old temporary file is removed and 
                    #the last records are renamed into a new temporary file 
            rm temperaturelogtemporary.txt;
            mv temperaturelog.txt temperaturelogtemporary.txt;
            COUNTER=0;
    fi
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1));
    echo $COUNTER;

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change ">" sign for "-ge".

```
if [[ $COUNTER -ge 100 ]];
```

Bash language is very very old - string and numeric comparisons performed with different keywords.

Comment: Note that `-ge` is `>=`, not `>`.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the accepted answer: while

```
[[ $COUNTER -ge 100 ]]
```

works, I still would recommend to use the equivalent

```
((COUNTER >= 100))
```

instead, because it is more readable.

Comment: when exactly does one use the semicolons? They are still needed right?

Comment: You need them only if you put multiple statements on one line. In your script, you can strip most of them.